# JavaScriptのテストツールについて

Tags: javascript, vue.js

***質問内容***

下部に書いています、「実現したいこと」を実現するにあたってテストコードを書くにあたり、どのようなツールを使うと、実現できるのかどなたかお教えいただけると嬉しいです。

***概要***

以下のような挙動において、それが正しく動作しているか？という観点でテストを行えるテストコードを書きたいのですが、恥ずかしながらテストコードはこれまでに書いた経験がなく、はじめてのことなので、どのようなツールを使うのがいいのか、調査を重ねてもいまいち理解できず、こちらを利用させてもらいました。

尚、このコンテンツ自体は`vue.js`で作られているものです。

***挙動内容***

**---以前---**

- プルダウンメニューの中から何か一つアイテム名を選択します（プルダウンのメニューは最低1個から最大は無制限まで存在します）
- ページがリダイレクトされ、トップページに戻ります
- トップページに戻りますが、選択したアイテムは記憶されているので、そのまま再度アイテムページへ遷移します
- ページ遷移後、選択されているアイテムの詳細情報を`api`から取得し画面に表示されます

**---今後---**

※以前との変更点は、アイテム選択後リダイレクト処理ではなく、そのまま`api`から情報を取得し画面に表示するようになったことです。

- プルダウンメニューの中から何か一つアイテム名を選択します（プルダウンのメニューは最低1個から最大は無制限まで存在します）
- アイテム名を選択後、`api`を叩いてそのアイテムに関する詳細情報を取得します
- 取得された詳細情報が画面に表示されます
- 再度プルダウンメニューからアイテムを選択し直した場合、上記の処理を繰り返します

***実現したいこと***
挙動内容に書いた「今後」の処理について、『リダイレクト処理がなされてないか？』ということが問題なく行われているか？をテストしたい。
『リダイレクト処理がなされてないか？』は、『アイテム選択前の`URL`とアイテム選択後の`URL`は同一か？』で判断したいと考えています。

Comment: > itmammothさん
ありがとうございます。
例までご提示いただき大変助かります。
これを参考に実装してみたいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript用のE2Eテストライブラリを使えば実現できます。
E2Eテストとは、簡単に言うと、ブラウザを自動操縦して行うテストです。
色んなライブラリがありますが、一例に[nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/)を紹介しておきます。

次のコードは、Googleで"nightwatch"というキーワードで検索して、結果ページに"Night Watch"という文字列が含まれていることを確認するテストコードです。

```js
module.exports = {
  'Demo test Google' : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://www.google.com')
      .waitForElementVisible('body')
      .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
      .waitForElementVisible('input[name=btnK]')
      .click('input[name=btnK]')
      .pause(1000)
      .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
      .end();
  }
};
```

このような感じでブラウザを自動操縦できますので、特定のプルダウンからアイテムを選択して、表示された詳細情報に特定の文字列が含まれているかとか、URLが変わってないかとかテストできますよ。